# start bash shell from where it stopped(due to error)

Tags: bash

I'm working on bash Unix shell. My script executes five 4gl files in order.if an error occurs in any of the files, the Scrip stops. But the problem is when we clear the error in the file and execute the script again..it should start from when it stopped (i.e from the step where the error is cleared)not from the first file.

Comment: What does executing an 4gl file do? Does it produce an output file with a known name? Also, do the executions gave to be in the given order or refund s it sufficient that they all happen?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this yourself:

```
if ! some-check-for-first-commmand; then
    do-something-with first.4gl
fi
if ! some-check-for-second-commmand; then
    do-something-with second.4gl
fi

# and so on
```

where "some-check-for-..." is something you write that checks if that 4gl file has been processed. It might look for some text in an output file, or the timestamp of an output file, or whatever you can do.